# Problem in changing mysql's root password in redhat

Tags: linux, mysql

I'm experiencing some problems while trying to change mysql's root password

I have just installed mysql in redhat. I am trying to execute /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password "password" but it is showing some error as below

```
/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed error: 
'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'

Check that mysqld is running and that the socket:
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!
```

I have tried "service mysqld start" but its showing some error

```
Starting MySQL..The server quit without updating PID file
(/var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.pid).
```

please help me

Comment: Did you try following what the error message told you?

Comment: both the cases are true mysqld not running and mysql.sock doesn't exist

Comment: This is an exact dupe or cross post of your earlier answer,  and it is a question about mysql, not really about passwords...

Comment: Any log details would be welcome.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions made by Bigmyx ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should try, first :

```
service mysqld status
```

If it's not running you should try to launch it :

```
service mysqld start
```

(or equivalent) to be sure the service is actually running. Then, check the user that is supposed to use mysqladmin has sufficient right (even if the error wouldn't  be this one if he hadn't). Finally, check that your database is listening on the good port.

Note that you can use service only as root, or with the proper sudo access.

Because of this message :

```
Starting MySQL..The server quit without updating PID 
file (/var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.pid).
```

You could try to move/remove the said file, and try to start your server again.

Comment: @Agemen MySQL is not running. How to start mysql

Comment: `service mysqld start`

Comment: I have tried it but showing following error:
Starting MySQL..The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.pid)

Comment: I am accessing it using SSH. Is there any option that blocks remote access

Comment: Edited my post according to TiZon suggestion. remote acces through ssh shouldn't be a problem. Add the result of `service mysqld start` to your main post ;-)

Comment: What user are you using to start mysqld? Be sure to run it as root...

Comment: I have logged as root user

Answer (score 0):

See the error in the log file in **/var/lib/mysql/hostname.err** 
Check the permissions of **/var/lib/mysql/db_dir** directories 
Or try to run mysqld mannually and see the error in the command's output.